# Serverside rendering react components in Ruby on rails project without asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, asset-pipeline, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a Ruby on rails 4 project where we are using React/Redux for frontend. We are using Webpack and gulp for compiling javascript and css. We do not use rails Asset pipeline at all, it is disabled from config. All assets compile to public folder and directly included on views. Now all react components are rendering on client side. It is having his own disadvantages like visual flicks before js is fully loaded and problems on passing initial props from backend to frontend.
Is there any good way to compile react components on server side without using asset pipeline and passing props directly from rails views?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure http://reactrb.org does this, but it does use asset pipeline.  The webpack components are brought in to the rails side, and then wrappers are automatically built so you can interface to the webpack components from your client side ruby components.

There was a lot of discussion on this at https://gitter.im/reactrb/chat and I don't know the details.

Also tutorial here: http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/reactrb-showcase dealing with this issue as well.

So you could just use http://reactrb.org or figure it by reading their code.

Comment: Reactrb offers writing react components in pure ruby. I don't like this aproach. Our react components written in jsx and compiled by webpack. Ony what I wanna to achive is rendering this components on serverside without using asset pipeline.

Comment: As I said it might not work for you, but I think the code may help you answer your question as it solves a very similar problem